# working with wordpress from Delphi

Tags: delphi, api, wordpress

I'm trying to work with a wordpress.com blog, by using Delphi. I want to upload movies, see/approve/modify comments, upload pictures, and I want to create a custom application to do all of those.

Please provide me if you know free or free to use for personal purpose components/Api's/etc, for Delphi 7 and up.

LE:Hope the question is not duplicated, I've searched on SO without finding any conclude results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109699/is-it-possible-to-use-wordpress-api-to-make-posts-on-wordpress-com has links to the API URL and the API specification

Answer (score 3):

ok, so I understand that i should use a XML-RPC component/class to work with wordpress. like this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphixml-rpc/   (or maybe you can give me other suggestions)

from here I found out how to work with XML-RPC from delphi

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-xmlrpc-from-delphi

LE: will try with bs-xmlrpc  also: http://code.google.com/p/bs-xmlrpc/downloads/list (has anyone worked with it?)

Comment: I'm also interested for building a Delphi application (XE10) to upload some thousands of posts to my WordPress site (because i have them in an incompatible format). the http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphixml-rpc not supports indy10 so i can't use it. Have you found something usefull ? Please give me any help you can.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using wordpress myself, but I notice there's a webservice plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/wsdl

I assume if you can add this plugin to your website, you could be able to import the WSDL into Delphi and have a wrapper unit generated you could call the WordPress API with.